# How does Rails keep the form data when validations fail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an 'create' action method in Rails and do:

```
def create
  @movie = Movie.new(movie_params)
  if @movie.save
    redirect_to @movie, notice: "Movie successfully created"
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Now, I have a few validations in place for the `Movie` model. In case those validations fail, and `@movie.save` returns false, I simply invoke the `new` template (without touching the `new` action, since `render :new` is the same as `render template: 'new'`.

I don't understand how Rails can keep the form data I already entered when it again renders that `new` view. What's going on behind the hood that allows it to do this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Let's try to understand this whole process point-wise

**Instance variables defined in the controller action are shared with the rendered views.**

In your case I'm assuming that there's a `new` action something like

```
def new
  @movie = Movie.new
end
```

And you have a corresponding view `new.html.erb` where you have created a form like this

```
= form_for @movie do |f|
```

Now, as you know the `@movie` object that you are passing in `form_for` method is defined in `new` action. Most of the times we don't pass any parameters to the `new` method in `new` action. The form fields are blank when you load the form because the attributes of the object(in your case `@movie`) are by default blank because we just initialize an empty object(`Movie.new`).

Let's assume your `Movie` model has a `name` attribute, Try doing this in your `new` action

```
def new
  @movie = Movie.new(name: 'Hello World!')
end
```

Now when you will load the new action, you will see `Hello World!` populated in your `name` text field because your `@movie` object is initialized with this value.

Also, keep in mind that Rails Convention-Over-Configuration automatically generates the form URL in this case, by default it points to the `create` action. When you submit the `form` the request is made to the create action. This takes me to the next point.

**When we submit the form all the filled in form values are sent to the action whose route matches with the form URL(in your case URL points to the `create` action)**

In `create` action you are receiving parameters in the form of a hash with model attributes(`Movie` attributes) as keys and the filled in information as their values. The first line in your `create` action is

```
@movie = Movie.new(movie_params)
```

This is a very important line of code, try to understand this. Let's assume your form had only one text field, i.e., `name`. Now `movie_params` is a method that looks like this

```
def movie_params
  params.require(:movie).permit(:name)
end
```

Now, the `movie_params` method will return a hash something like `{ 'name' => 'Hello World!' }`, now you are passing this hash as a parameter to `Movie.new` method.

So now, after breaking up the code, the first line of your create action looks like

```
@movie = Movie.new({ name: 'Hello World!' })
```

That means your `@movie` instance variable contains an object of `Movie` class with `name` attribute set to `Hello World!`. Here, when after initialization, if you do `@movie.name` it will return `Hello World!`.

Now, in the second line you are calling `@movie.save` that returned `false` due to failed validation in your case as you have already mentioned in the question. As it returned `false` the execution will go to the `else` part. Now this takes me to the next point.

**Calling `render :action`(in your case `render :new`) in the controller  renders only the view that belongs to that action and does not execute that action code.**

In your case, you called `render :new`, so there you are actually rendering the `new.html.erb` view in create action. In other words, you are just using the code in `new.html.erb` and not in `new` action. Here, `render :new` does not actually invoke the new action, it's still in the create action but rendering the `new.html.erb` view.

Now, in `new.html.erb` you have created a form that looks like

```
= form_for @movie do |f|
```

Now as my explained under my first point, the instance variables that are declared in the action are shared by the rendered view, in this case `@movie` object that you have defined in `create` action is shared by the rendered `new.html.erb` in create action. In our case, in `create` action the `@movie` object was initialized with some values that were received in the parameters(`movie_params`), now when `new.html.erb` is rendered in the `else`, the same `@movie` object is used in the form by default. You got the point right, you see the magic here?

This is how Rails works and that's why its awesome when we follow the convention! :)

https://gist.github.com/jcasimir/1210155

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/layouts_and_rendering.html

Hope the above examples cleared your doubts, if not, feel free to drop your queries in the comment box below.

Comment: this is a solid response, but the poster also asked for official sources as references. Add that and I'd say it's worth the bounty!

Comment: @toobulkeh Added official sources and references.

Comment: @RSB - this response helped me BIG time.  I didn't know that my object in the create method needs to be named the same as it is in the new form in order to repopulate the form.  Do you teach programming classes online?

Comment: I have been in stackoverflow for more than 6 years and never ever I have seen an answer with this much details. Hats of @RajdeepSingh ...

Answer (score 2):

`form_for` helper takes data from `@movie` variable. In `create` action forms data assigns to `@movie` variable. When you call `render :new` form_for takes column's data from `@movie` variable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how deep under the hood you want to go, but basically when you POST to the create method the data is passed to the `params`, the `params` being just a key:value pairs where the key and the value are strings, but rails has a special syntax and methods for turning into hashes. `params` data is passed the `Movie` model to be processed and the result stored in `@movie`. When  the form is rendered the `@movie` date is passed back to the form - that data is used to repopulate the form.

I would recommend this [blog post](http://6ftdan.com/allyourdev/2015/01/05/dealing-with-rails-4-forms-and-params/) and [the rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters)for further reading.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain little bit:
in method create first of all we set instance variable

```
@movie = Movie.new(movie_params)
```

`@movie` at this moment has fields filled with `movie_params`
and after validates brakes we say to Rails 'render :new' with variable `@movie`.

This is the same if we assign attributes into form:

```
= form_for Movie.new(movie_params) do ...
```

Answer (score 0):

When you submit your form. You call create method where all values of `movie_params` are initializes in `@movie`. Now due to any reason code break then you call `render new` for same object (`@movie`). So form come up with values.

Means in whole process your `@movie` object persisted.